# ソースからインストールしたGitのアップデートをしたい

Tags: git, centos

http://tomoyamkung.net/2014/08/27/linux-git-install/

こちらを参考にCentOSにGitをソースからインストールしました。
今回最新版がリリースされたのでアップデートしたいのですが、ソースからインストールしたGitのアンインストールのやりかたがわかりません。

具体的なやり方を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

手元で確認してみましたが、make uninstall が無いみたいなので、素手で消していくほかないような気がします。

他に良い手があるかもしれませんが、参照されたURLの方法で`make`まで実行した後、例えば、一般ユーザで

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test_root
$ make prefix=/tmp/test_root install
```

などとして、/tmp/test_root にインストール後、`find /tmp/test_root -type f` の結果のファイルを確認しながら削除すると良いと思います。(./configure時に--prefix等を指定していなければ /usr/local 以下にインストールされているはずです)

ただの野良のtar.gzを入れるくらいなので、その環境にもよると思いますが、男らしく最新版のソースで、make install で上書きしてしまっても良いかもしれません。

Comment: ほんとですね、質問者さんの提示のサイトのバージョンでもuninstallルールはありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

その他の方法としまして、git コマンドを使う方法もあるかと思います。git には以下のオプションがあります。

```
--exec-path
--html-path
--man-path
--info-path
```

それぞれのオプションの意味は `man git` で確認していただくとして、

```
$ find $(dirname $(which git)) -name "git*" -ls
$ for opt in html man info exec
  do
    find "$(git --${opt}-path)" -name "git*" -ls
  done
```

などとすれば、インストールされたファイルを精度は低いながらそれなりに確認できるかと思います。ご参考までにどうぞ。